# invalid user-defined conversion error

Tags: c++

I am creating simple program that stores kids that attends to certain classroom , each kid has an array that defines their friends.

I am experiencing

> error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'Kids*' to 'Kids&&' [-fpermissive]|

error.
i am using this  code

```
struct Kids{
    int *friends;
    Kids(){};
    Kids( int n ){
        friends = new int[n];
    }
};
class Classroom{
    Classroom(){
        cin >> size;
        kids = new Kids[ size ];
        for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
            kids[i] = new Kids(i);
        }
    }
private:
    int size;
    Kids *kids;
};
```

Why is this line

```
kids[i] = new Kids[i];
```

considering by compiler as attempt to convert Kids* to Kids&& while i am creating a new instance of node e.g dynamicly allocating it thus passing it as Kids*?

Thanks for help!

Comment: `kids[i]` is of type `Kids`. `new Kids[i]` is of type `Kids*` (an array of `Kids`). I think you mean `new Kids(i)`, in which case the result would be of type `Kids`.

Comment: @Qix `new` always returns a pointer type (or throws).

Comment: `std::vector<Kids> kids;` and `std::vector<int> friends;` -- This gets rid of the `size` member and doesn't require any manual memory management.

Comment: can anybody explain why the compiler message refers to `Kids&&` ... and not just `Kids&`?

Comment: Why are those ` new Kids` in a `Classroom`? Shouldn't they be on the `Block`?

Comment: @davidhigh gcc does weird things like that with its error messages

Comment: @krzaq You're right, I meant `new Kids[i]` is a type `Kids**` and `new Kids(i)` is of type `Kids*`. Idk why I messed that up.

Answer (score 5):

`new Kids(i)` creates a `Kids` object initialized by `i` and returns pointer to it.

`kids[i]` is a `Kids` object (lvalue), not a pointer.

Those types are simply not compatible.

The `kids` array is already allocated by the first instruction (`kids = new Kids[ size ];`), there's no need to do it again.

If you want to initialize each kid with it's index, you should be able to just type:

```
kids[i] = Kids(i);
```

But you seem to breaking the [rule of three/fize/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), so YMMV.

By the way, instead of doing all the hard work yourself, you should let the library do it for you and use a collection/smart pointer instead of managing your resources manually. Use [`std::vector<Kids>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::unique_ptr<Kids[]>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), whichever fits your needs.

Comment: uh , i noticed typo , it should have been kids[i] = new Kids(i)

Comment: @J.dd that wouldn't make any difference, you still get a *pointer* to a `Kids` object instead of the object itself. Are you experienced with another language that doesn't use pointers?

Comment: @MarkRansom yep , i am experienced with js/php , trying to make step up and learn c++

Comment: @J.dd [See this](http://ideone.com/V8bmj4).  No pointers are necessary.

Comment: @J.dd updated. The general rule of C++ lately is that you shouldn't need to visibly use `new` (almost) at all and `delete` pretty much completely. Use smart pointers and containers instead.

Comment: @krzaq Thanks for advices! I have one more question . By inicializating kids[i] = Kids(i) , is it creating new behind the scenes? I am dynamicly creating the node so i could assign an pointer pointing to it or not?

Comment: It does create an unnamed object, but not on the free store (heap), then assigns it to the object residing at the `i`th position of the `kids` array. Please note that `new Kids[size]` created `size` of `Kids` objects, not references/pointers/handles. I'm not sure how to make a js/php analogy to this.

Comment: @J.dd Maybe this: in C++ almost everything has value semantics, like `struct`s in C#. If you copy an object, you end up with a deep copy, not a second reference to the same object. (minus objects that define their own copy operations differently). This comes with lots of gotchas at what actually counts as a value, but I think that this is a reasonable description.

Comment: @J.dd -  The quick answer to your last question is this -- it's doing exactly what you see.  I'm not joking.  It's creating a Kids object on the right side, and assigning it to the array element on the left side.  There is no sneaky reference thing going on, like in Java or some other languages.  It is using assignment, just like you would see if it were a "simple" type like an `int` or `double`.

Comment: @J.dd Basically, `new` tells the compiler, "Make me an instance, give me its address, and let me do what I want with it", while direct assignment says, "Make me an instance, and take care of all the messy stuff for me"; direct assignment generally creates on the stack, and `new` generally allocates on the heap, but this isn't guaranteed.  If it's created with `new`, you have to manually delete it when you're done with it; if it's created with direct assignment, it'll be deallocated automatically when it goes out of scope.  Either way, you can obtain a pointer to it if necessary.